# Finding the residue of a function at a point

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Find the residue at $\pi$ for the function defined by $$\dfrac{z^2+\sin\left(z\right)}{\left(z-\pi\right)^4}$$

I thought I could do this using the 'gh rule' however this gives $$\dfrac{\pi^2+\sin\left(\pi\right)}{4\left(\pi-\pi\right)^3}$$ which is undefined.
Is there an alternative way to calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the general rule for pole of order $p$.

Here if we note $f(z) = \frac{z^2+\sin(z)}{(z-\pi)^4}$ we have $$Res(f,\pi)=\frac{1}{3!} \lim_{z\to \pi} (z^2+\sin(z))'''.$$ It is easy to compute the third derivative here. This gives $-\cos(z)$. Hence $$Res(f,\pi)=\frac{1}{6}.$$

Comment: How do we know to compute the third derivative?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what is that $gh$ formula but residue of $f(z)$ at a pole $c$ of order $n$ is given by $$\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\rightarrow c}(z-c)^nf(z)$$

In this case we have $$\frac{1}{6}$$